# Template hierarchy html with taxonomy in 6.2

Tags: custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

Following the doc:
for a single post wpress 6.2 loads single.html ( and if none index.html) ok.
If we follow hierarchy diagram, a post with specific taxonomy XX will be :
**single-XX.html** ( ie single-{slug of taxonomy} ) as it is in php.

But this doesn't work, stays to single.html. What's wrong ? unforeseen ?

(by the way, same thing with tag )

thanks

Comment: I don’t see any such template in the template hierarchy diagram. Where did you see that?

Comment: I Ask gpt3 . Maybe wrong answer. In any case, how to have a direct template depending of item in taxonomy.

Comment:  Yet more proof that Chat GPT doesn’t actually know anything. Always prefer official documentation. Anyway, the answer is that you can’t create a template file for that. For classic themes you would need to add a check inside the template itself, but I’m not sure what you’d do for a block theme.

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomies only have archive pages.
If a taxonomy is associated with a post then that post can be rendered with single-post.html, or any other template in the template hierarchy that could match a post.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
taxonomy-{slug of taxonomy}.html
```

For example, I have a taxonomy with the slug "network-category" for the custom post type "network". My category archive page template is named:

```
taxonomy-network-category.html
```

My URL for the category archive page for the "school" network category is:

```
{my domain}/network-category/school/
```

I found I could also create a template page for a specific category by appending -{category name}, for example:

```
taxonomy-network-category-school.html
```

(I am not sure how recently this naming convention was introduced for WordPress FSE, but it works for me now.)

See also the official documentation at the [Taxonomy Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) page of WordPress' Develop Resources.